# Delete files with regular expression

Tags: bash, unix, regex, rm

I Tried to delete files that starts with A and ends with 2 numbers but It doesn't do a thing.
What I tried:

```
rm ^A*[0..9]2$
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use the following command to delete all files matching your criteria:

```
ls | grep -P "^A.*[0-9]{2}$" | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

How it works:

1. `ls` lists all files (one by line since the result is piped).
2. `grep -P "^A.*[0-9]{2}$"` filters the list of files and leaves only those that match the regular expression `^A.*[0-9]{2}$`

   - `.*` indicates any number of occurrences of `.`, where `.` is a wildcard matching any character.
   - `[0-9]{2}` indicates exactly two occurrences of `[0-9]`, that is, any digit.
3. `xargs -d"\n" rm` executes `rm line` once for every `line` that is piped to it.

> Where am I wrong?

For starters, `rm` doesn't accept a regular expression as an argument. Besides the wildcard `*`, every other character is treated literally.

Also, your regular expression is slightly off. For example, `*` means any occurrences of `...` in a regular expression, so `A*` matches `A`, `AA`, etc. and even an empty string.

For more information, visit [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Beware of spaces in file names.

Comment: The `-d"\n` switch fixes the spaces problem.

Comment: Note - some distros (like Mac OS) don't have a `grep -P` (Perl regex). `grep -E` may work in this case.

Comment: I prefer using `-I` with `xargs` and always test with non-lethal commands first: `xargs -d"\n" -I {} echo "{}"`

Comment: Parsing `ls`? See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/108618) which points to [this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Because of the pitfalls you may `rm` what you don't want to.

Comment: @Frg Beware of newlines in file names. Or other strange characters.

Comment: this won't work if `ls` or `grep` aliased with `--color=always`  option and you will need to do `\ls | \grep ...`

Comment: This is not the most robust solution (spaces in filenames), especially considering `find` does all this in one command.

Answer (score 81):

Or using `find`:

```
find your-directory/ -name 'A*[0-9][0-9]' -delete
```

This solution will deal with *weird* file names.

Comment: This is a great solution. I prefer it because it is simpler and you can omit the -delete flag at the end first to see if your regex is correct before mass deleting your files.

Comment: Furthermore you have more control on what you delete, for example adding `-type f`

Comment: Can this be used to delete files and folders? It does not work for non empty folders.

Comment: @Alex nope, the directory must be empty (it wasn't an OP requirement anyway), you can use the `xargs` approach with `rm -f`.

Comment: also obligatory link to article about parsing ls

Comment: do we need specify `mindepth`?

Answer (score 19):

See the [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) section of the bash man page:

```
rm A*[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: worked nicely for me.

Comment: This was the simplest, yet complete answer to the question.

Comment: Will this work if the folder has a lot of files?

Answer (score 4):

`find` command works with regexes as well.

Check which files are gonna to be deleted

```
find . -regex '^A.*[0-9]{2}$'
```

Delete files

```
find . -regex '^A.*[0-9]{2}$' -delete
```

Comment: This one doesn't work in it's current form. You need to define `-regextype egrep` to make `{x,y}` type quantifiers work.

Answer (score 3):

This works on my mac:

`rm $(ls | grep -e '^A*[0..9]2$')`

Answer (score 2):

The solution with regexp is 200 times better, even with that you can see which file will be deleted before using the command, cutting off the final pipe:

```
ls | grep -P "^A.*[0-9]{2}$"
```

Then if it's correct just use:

```
ls | grep -P "^A.*[0-9]{2}$" | xargs -d "\n" rm
```

This is 200 times better because if you work with Unix it's important to know how to use grep. It's very powerful if you know how to use it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add much beyond what [Dennis's 4 year old answer](http://superuser.com/a/392878/302463) already says.

Comment: "200 times" is a pretty specific. Lots of other commands are very powerful too, all you need to do is learn how to use them.